# Gnu parallel: how to build a command using the --link option to 'expand' positional arguments?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

### The problem

I'm using GNU parallel and want to pass two files to a program using the `:::` operator. My directory tree looks like this:

```
$ ls 

SRR6301073_pass_1_trimmed.fq  
SRR6301073_pass_2_trimmed.fq  
SRR6301129_pass_1_trimmed.fq  
SRR6301129_pass_2_trimmed.fq  
...
```

The following code:

```
#!bin/bash
ones=$(find SRR*pass*1*.fq)
twos=$(find SRR*pass*2*.fq)    
parallel --link echo ::: $ones ::: $twos
```

Produces:

```
SRR6301033_pass_1_trimmed.fq SRR6301033_pass_2_trimmed.fq
SRR6301034_pass_1_trimmed.fq SRR6301034_pass_2_trimmed.fq
...
```

But I actually need the output to look like this:

```
-1 SRR6301033_pass_1_trimmed.fq -2 SRR6301033_pass_2_trimmed.fq
-1 SRR6301034_pass_1_trimmed.fq -2 SRR6301034_pass_2_trimmed.fq
...
```

#### What I've tried already

This:

```
$ parallel --link echo -1 ::: $ones -2 ::: $twos
```

produces

```
-1 SRR6301033_pass_1_trimmed.fq SRR6301033_pass_2_trimmed.fq
-1 SRR6301034_pass_1_trimmed.fq SRR6301034_pass_2_trimmed.fq
```

and this:

```
$ parallel --link echo -1 ::: $ones ::: $twos
```

Produces:

```
-1 SRR6301033_pass_1_trimmed.fq -2
-1 SRR6301034_pass_1_trimmed.fq SRR6301033_pass_2_trimmed.fq
-1 SRR6301037_pass_1_trimmed.fq SRR6301034_pass_2_trimmed.fq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
parallel --dry-run --link echo -1 {1} -2 {2} ::: a b ::: c d
```

**Output**

```
echo -1 a -2 c
echo -1 b -2 d
```